# Select input element based on label text

Tags: jquery, label, selector

Is there a simpler way to grab an input element based the text content of the label?

Below i wrote a jquery selector to grab the input element associated with the label "MyCustomItem"

```js
$('input#'+$('label:contains("MyCustomItem")').attr('for'))[0]
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="ctl06_ctl07_tb_item_979_CF_4558" class="col-sm-4 form-control-label control-label">MyCustomItem</label>
    <div id="ctl06_ctl07_item_979_CF_4558" class="col-sm-8">
        <input name="ctl06$ctl07$tb_item_979_CF_4558" type="text" id="ctl06_ctl07_tb_item_979_CF_4558" class="form-control">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That looks like the best way to me.

Comment: Technically yes.  Remove the `input` part of the selector so that jQuery/sizzle can shortcircuit your selector to a simple id lookup.